# How to refresh subreport on Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, refresh, subreport

Is there any way to refresh a subreport in Reporting Services?

When I change something on a subreport file and back to the main report, I have to delete the subreport object and include a new instance again to get my preview updated.

Is there any way to update the sub report object in the main report without having to delete and include the same again?

Comment: Does the top level refresh button not work? How are you running the report from the website or in a development tool?

Comment: i'm on the visual studio 2008 [Designer], when i click on the refresh buttom on the preview, the report is not updated!!! (but the rdl file was changed)

Answer (score 8):

Actually I think the answer is to ensure that you preview or rebuild the sub-report before you view it in the parent report.
The simplest way to rebuild a subreport is to preview it in BIDS, but you can also right-click | build on the report in the Solution Explorer.  Alternatively, rebuild your whole report project if that's easier than rebuilding individual reports.

Comment: Previewing the updated subreport (as a stand-alone) worked for me. Rebuilding the solution did not.

Answer (score 2):

In BIDS, in your top level report, you should have a Subreport object.  That object is essentially just a pointer to another rdl in the project.  This should update automatically.  What i think you're seeing is BIDS loading a stale version of the subreport.  If this happens try closing BIDS all the way down and open the project back up again and rerun the parent report.  It should have the updated subreport.

This is all assuming that you've got a report project in bids with standalone reports instead of embedding reports in aspx pages.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post, but as can happen, I was someone with the issue as well and landed here through searching google. I'm not sure if the OP is using Visual Studio 2008 like one of the commenters is, as am I, but what I found is that while preview on the main report is not showing an updated sub-report, I can see the update by right clicking on the main report in the solution explorer and selecting "run". It doesn't seem to take much longer if at all to open the separate run window.

Comment: that was almost 5 years ago. Many of us have moved on :P